# Trying to create a simple trigger SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

I'm trying to create a simple trigger just like an audit.

The error is

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sampleTrigger, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near '@OLDName'.

Can anyone help me ?

Here's my sample code .

```
CREATE TRIGGER sampleTrigger 
ON tblEmployee
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @OLDName varchar(50)
    declare @NewName varchar(50)

    Select @OLDName = EmployeeName from deleted
    Select @NewName = EmployeeName from inserted

    insert into Audit
    values (Getdate()@OLDName, @NewName)
END
GO
```

Comment: Your trigger is fundamentally broken anyway. Should be something like `insert into Audit Select Getdate(), i.EmployeeName, d.EmployeeName FROM inserted i FULL OUTER JOIN deleted d ON i.EmployeeId = d.EmployeeId`

Answer (score 0):

To fix the syntax, you're simply missing a comma;

```
insert into Audit
    values (Getdate(), @OLDName, @NewName)
                     ^ this one
```